# PHP UPDATE data where there are ID matches

Tags: php, mysql

I'm passing an id from a URL from the previous page and then try to update database values in the row of that id. I feel like I'm close. I'm able to update the value `librarian_fname` when I add into the update query the specific id number, but when I try and pass that value through the code, it must not be picking it up because it won't update when I use `id = '$id'`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. And I am still learning so forgive me if this isn't perfect.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id;
?>
    <?php
  // This function will run within each post array including multi-dimensional arrays
function ExtendedAddslash(&$params)
{
        foreach ($params as &$var) {
            // check if $var is an array. If yes, it will start another ExtendedAddslash() function to loop to each key inside.
            is_array($var) ? ExtendedAddslash($var) : $var=addslashes($var);
            unset($var);
        }
}

// Initialize ExtendedAddslash() function for every $_POST variable
ExtendedAddslash($_POST);   

            $librarian_fname = $_POST['librarian_fname'];
            $id = $_POST['id'];
 ?>

        <?php
         if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $dbuser = '';
            $dbpass = '';
            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

            if(! $conn ) {
               die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            } 
            $sql = "UPDATE table SET librarian_fname = '$librarian_fname' WHERE id = '$id'";
            mysql_select_db('Events');
            $result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

            if(! $result ) {
               die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            mysql_close($conn);
            header("Location: search.php");
         }

         else {
            ?>

            <?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$librarian_fname = $id = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   $librarian_fname = test_input($_POST["librarian_fname"]);
  $id = test_input($_POST["id"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]);?>">
                    <legend><b>Appointment Topic</b></legend>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $id; ?>">
                    <label for="librarian_fname">First Name <em>*</em></label>
                    <input type="text" name="librarian_fname" size="50" required="no" validateat="onsubmit" message="Please enter your first name."> input name = "add" type = "submit" id = "add" value = "Submit">
                </form>
                <?php
         }
      ?>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason your learning is using the deprecated mysql_ interface functions (which are removed in PHP 7) and not learning PDO or mysqli ?  One of things you need to learn is how to *debug* your programs. Asking the internet to debug your programs is *not* efficient or scalable. I suggest you echo out the value of $id before it gets included in the SQL statement, Echo out the SQL statement, and find out if the code is even reaching that point.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I'm new to PHP so I will take a look at PDO/mysqli. Thank you for the link. I'm learning to debug also, and attempted to echo out the id at the top of my page, but it isn't passing into the SQL statement.

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE table SET librarian_fname = $librarian_fname WHERE id = $id ";  replace it

Comment: @MujeebuRahman: doesn't make any difference (in MySQL) that a numeric literal is enclosed in single quotes. Looks like we are suggesting (guessing) fixes without an understanding of what the actual problem is. And its unlikely that the recommended fix is going to make one whit of difference.

Comment: Hi Mujeebu, when I try that, which I have tried before I get the following: Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table SET librarian_fname = test WHERE id =' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]);?>">
                        <legend><b>Appointment Topic</b></legend>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
                        <label for="librarian_fname">First Name <em>*</em></label>
                        <input type="text" name="librarian_fname" size="50" required="no" validateat="onsubmit" message="Please enter your first name."> <input name = "add" type = "submit" id = "add" value = "Submit">
                        <input type="reset" name="resetButton" id="resetButton" vvalue="Reset Form" style="margin-right: 20px;" />
     </form>
```

Comment: That was the issue. I figured it was something simple. That actually makes sense to why I would need to get it in the form first. Thank you!

Comment: i think your id  hidden value is empty

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the issues may be that `TABLE` is a MySQL reserved word.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

If we want to use a reserved word as an identifier (e.g. table name) it must be escaped. The normative pattern in MySQL to escape identifiers is to enclose them in single backtick characters, e.g.

```
 UPDATE `table` SET
```

That works whether the identifier is a reserved word or not. Better would be to use a different name for the table.

---

Be aware that the code appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Potentially unsafe values incorporated into the text of a SQL statement must be properly escaped (e.g. using mysqli_real_escape_string)

https://xkcd.com/327/

The preferred pattern is to *not* incorporate values into the SQL text, and instead use a *prepared statement* with *bind placeholders*.

Comment: Thank you, @spencer7593. I used a different table name but didn't share it here. Understand about the SQL Injection, still learning that also, but this particular code will be in a password protected folder. I realize attacks could still happen, though.

Comment: There's a comment on the question that says ....  when i try that, I get this error:  **`... the right syntax to use near 'table SET librarian_fname = `** which indicates that MySQL is encountering the syntax problem starting at `table`. Debugging code isn't super difficult. But it's usually *not* made easier by examining and evaluating code that is *different* from the code that is being executed.

Comment: Whether the code is in a password protected foler or not, I recommend learning good coding practices. It's actually easier (less work) than unlearning bad coding practices which have been reinforced with practice. Better to practice the right way. And there's no need to litter StackOverflow with yet more examples of insecure code.

Comment: Any recommendations on where to learn best practices? The debugging article was great, so thank you.

Comment: I strongly recommend the OWASP project. That can be a bit overwhelming, but one quick way to get an overview is to start with the "Cheat Sheets".  For example, the "SQL Injection Cheat Sheet".  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Cheat_Sheet_Series  ... or at least start with the Top Ten. (Some employers expect web development candidates to be familiar at least a few of the Top Ten web vulnerabilities  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project and mitigation strategies. In this day of criminal hackers, there is no excuse to writing code that is known to be vulnerable.)

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at it.